# user input validation for python

Tags: python, validation, logic

I have a very simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to and am very new to python. I need to check a users input to see if the user has entered one of four operations. The operation are '^', '&', '|', and 'q' for quit. The user will be prompt again if they dont enter a valid operation so a while loop is needed, is there a way to test for all the operations in a single line?  here is the code I have so far

```
    operation = input("enter an operation to be used\n")
    print('operation chosen:', operation)
    error = ("please enter |, &, ^, or q" )
    while operation != '&' 
    print(error)
```

Comment: Just use the `if` but a long one. `if '|' in operation or '&' in operation or '^' in operation or 'q' in operation`.

Comment: I was going to try that but the problem is if the user doesn't input an operation the second time the error will go through and they will not be reprompt again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup will only accept inputs that are in `(^&|q)` the loop will cycle until user inputs of of those choices, the beginning initializes `operation` to a value **not** in the list to start the loop.

```
operation = 'x'
while operation not in ('^&|q'):
    operation = input('Enter operation from "^%|q": ')
print('Operation chosen: {}'.format(operation))
```

> ```
> Enter operation from "^%|q": a
> Enter operation from "^%|q": s
> Enter operation from "^%|q": d
> Enter operation from "^%|q": ^
> Operation chosen: ^
> ```

This route will do the same and prompt the user with a *Invalid* message, although this route requires a input before the loop to initialize `operation`

```
operation = input('Enter operation from "^&|q": ')
while operation not in ('^&|q'):
    operation = input('Invalid entry. Please choose from "^%|q": ')
print('Operation chosen: {}'.format(operation))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all valid operations in an array and check the input against that array; correct input should break the loop, an incorrect input should raise the error and loop again.

Sample code below

```
allowd_operations= ['|','&','^', 'q' ]
operation = ''

while True:
    operation = input("enter an operation to be used\n")
    if operation in allowd_operations:
        # correct input
        break

    print('operation chosen:', operation)
    error = ("please enter |, &, ^, or q" )
    print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to your Python journey. Here's a way to test user input with recursion and a function, which is helpful for larger projects, and those where some of these variables can change:

```
def checkinput(userinput):
    if userinput in ('|^&q'):
        return userinput
    else:
        loopinputline = input("please enter |, &, ^, or q\n" )
        return checkinput(loopinputline)


operation = str(input("enter an operation to be used\n"))
finalinput = checkinput(operation)
print('operation chosen:', finalinput)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['^','&','|','q']
operation = raw_input('Enter operation from "^&|q": ')
while operation not in list1:
    operation = raw_input('Invalid entry. Please choose from "^&|q": ')
print(operation)
```

as per the question asked the user has to enter only one option. for answer by @cash_the stampede ,  if the user enters '^&' still it is accepting as the right answer, which should not be the case. so the above is just small correction.